# MathJax: MathJax Preview font change

Tags: android, mathjax, typesetting

I am using MathJax-2.7 (source: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html) on android. The MathJax Preview of the mathematical formula displayed initially has a different font as compared to the font (Computer Modern) after typesetting is complete. 
I am trying to make the text font of the preview same as that after typesetting is complete. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

we can't prevent to this , you can only load the MathJax.js file fastly, then possible different fonts visibility will in microseconds
so load 'fast-preview.js'